# Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - output

Tags: php, mysql, database

I get this error: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
<?php

 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
echo"Connected";
 mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());
echo"Database Found";

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(id, author, title, savetext) VALUES ('1','id1')") or     die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(id, author, title, savetext) VALUES ('2','author1')") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(id, author, title, savetext) VALUES ('3','title1')") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(id, author, title, savetext) VALUES ('4','savetext1')") or die(mysql_error());

echo"Data Inserted";

 mysql_close();

 ?>
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/crDIX.png

Comment: What about that error message don't you understand? It talls you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: *Obligatory lashing about using mysql rather than mysqli or PDO*

I really think StackOverflow could automate this -- anytime someone posts PHP code that uses a mysql function, it could automatically add a comment about sql injection.

Comment: @JohnConde Beats the heck outta me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to insert values into each column with individual statements? No no no, just do it all in one statement.

```
mysql_query("INSERT into $table (id, author, title, savetext) VALUES ('id1', 'author1', 'title1', 'savetext1')");
```

Now, go read up on Mysqli before heads explode on StackOverflow because mysql commands are deprecated and vulnerable to sql injections and other bad things.

Answer (score 0):

Self explanatory. You're inserting 2 values into 3 columns.

If id is an auto-incrementing column, you don't even need to insert into it. MySQL will do that for you.

If you don't want to insert data into specific columns, you can either not include them in the fields list or insert NULL into them:

`INSERT INTO $table(id, author) VALUES ('1','id1')`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to give values to all mentioned columns..

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(`id`, `author`, `title`, `savetext`)

   ```
   VALUES ('1','id1', '', '')")
   ```

   OR
2. Skip columns[names] that have no value to insert..

   `mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table(`id`,`author`) VALUES ('1','id1')")`